# Docker Image Timestamp Issue

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I've created a brand new image but it shows `50 years ago timestamp`, please find attached the snippet.  Any idea why?

I used the below steps in Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11

VOLUME /tmp

COPY build/libs /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app/test-service.jar"]
```

and my docker version is

```
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
```

Gradle 6.0.1 build tool, and Google Jib plugin to create image

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '1.8.0'
}

jib {
    from {
        image = 'openjdk:11'
    }
    to {
        image = 'test-service'
    }
    container {
        jvmFlags = ['-Xms512m', '-Xdebug']
        mainClass = 'com.sample.Application'
    }
    allowInsecureRegistries=true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the commands used to create the image, docker and other tooling versions involved, with enough detail to recreate the issue if possible.

Comment: @BMitch updated the issue. Thanks for your prompt response!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's from Google Jib. For reproducibility they don't set a date, or they explicitly set the date to the zero value, which is the epoch in 1970.

There is a FAQ entry for this: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-is-my-image-created-48-years-ago

> For reproducibility purposes, Jib sets the creation time of the
>   container images to the Unix epoch (00:00:00, January 1st, 1970 in
>   UTC). If you would like to use a different timestamp, set the
>   `jib.container.creationTime / <container><creationTime>` parameter to an
>   ISO 8601 date-time. You may also use the value `USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
>   to set the creation time to the actual build time, but this sacrifices
>   reproducibility since the timestamp will change with every build.
>
> ### Setting `creationTime` parameter
>
> Maven:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>   <container>
>     <creationTime>2019-07-15T10:15:30+09:00</creationTime>
>   </container>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Gradle:
>
> ```
> jib.container.creationTime = '2019-07-15T10:15:30+09:00'
> ```

Comment: Used useCurrentTimestamp=true which works fine, you're star!

Comment: The  useCurrentTimestamp  is deprecated, now use the: jib.container.creationTime with USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/0050ee4c2ca38a8ce7e48b529e84d0a409179318/jib-gradle-plugin/CHANGELOG.md#changed-13

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the build reproducibility of the build but with a more sensible creation time by using the timestamp of the commit which is being build:

```
def getGitCommitTime() {
    String[] parts = 'git show -s --format=%ci'.execute().text.trim().split(" ")
    return (parts[0]+'T'+parts[1]+parts[2])
}
...
jib.container.creationTime = getGitCommitTime()
```